# MLE and Cross Entropy for Conditional Probabilities

Tags: neural-networks, maximum-likelihood, cross-entropy

I'm trying to understand the relationship between maximum likelihood estimation for a function of the type $p(y^{(i)}|x^{(i)};\theta)$ and the related cross entropy minimization.

For a single variable this is straight forward. I am using the notation from "Deep Learning" by Goodfellow et al.

$\hat{\theta}_{ML} = \operatorname{argmax}_{\theta} \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N} \log p_{model}(x^{(i)};\theta)$. Writing the empirical distribution of the data as $\hat{p}_{data}$ we can re-write the function inside the argmax as $E_{\hat{p}_{data}}[\log p_{model}(x;\theta)]$. Maximizing this function is equivalent to minimizing the cross entropy $H(\hat{p}_{data},p_{model})$. Ok, easy enough.

I'm confused how this generalizes to the case where we are maximizing the likelihood of a model of the type $p_{model}(y^{(i)}|x^{(i)};\theta)$ as we might do in a supervised learning framework.

Trying to follow the same line of reasoning we should be able to derive a statement that maximizing the likelihood $\hat{\theta}_{ML} = \operatorname{argmax} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^{N} \log p_{model}(y^{(i)}|x^{(i)};\theta)$ is equivalent to minimizing the cross entropy between $\hat{p}_{data}(Y|X)$ and $p_{model}(Y|X)$. However $H(\hat{p}_{data}(Y|X),p_{model}(Y|X))$ is a random variable w.r.t. $X$ so the analogy doesn't hold.

My best guess is that maximizing the likelihood in this scenario is equivalent to minimizing the expected cross entropy between $\hat{p}_{data}(Y|X)$ and $p_{model}(Y|X)$ taken over the empirical distribution of $X$. Written out this would be $E_{\hat{p}_{data}(X)}[H(\hat{p}_{data}(Y|X),p_{model}(Y|X))]$.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, I realized that defining the conditional cross-entropy in my previous answer is not even needed, we can directly draw the equivalence between conditional MLE maximization and classical cross entropy minimization:
\begin{eqnarray} 
\hat{\theta}_{ML} &=& \arg\max_{\theta} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^{N} \log p_{model}(y^{(i)}|x^{(i)};\theta) \nonumber \\
&=& \arg\min_{\theta} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^{N} - \log p_{model}(y^{(i)}|x^{(i)};\theta) \nonumber \\
&=& \arg\min_{\theta} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^{N} - \log p_{model}(y^{(i)}|x^{(i)};\theta) - \log p(x^{(i)}) \nonumber \\
&=& \arg\min_{\theta} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^{N} - \log p_{model}(y^{(i)}|x^{(i)};\theta) - \log p_{model}(x^{(i)}|\theta) \nonumber \\
&=& \arg\min_{\theta} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^{N} - \log \left( p_{model}(y^{(i)}|x^{(i)};\theta)p_{model}(x^{(i)}|\theta) \right) \nonumber \\
&=& \arg\min_{\theta} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^{N} - \log  p_{model}(y^{(i)}, x^{(i)}|\theta) \nonumber \\
 &\approx& \arg\min_{\theta} \left(\mathbb{E}_{p_{data}(x,y)}\left[ -\log p_{model}(y,x|\theta) \right] \right) \nonumber \\
 &=& \arg\min_{\theta} \left(\mathbb{E}_{p_{data}(x,y)}\left[ -\log p_{model(\theta)}(y,x) \right] \right) \nonumber 
\end{eqnarray}
In the third step we subtracted logarithm of true and unknown probability of drawing the sample $x^{(i)}$, which does not change the argmax, as it is independent of $\theta$.
In the fourth step, we defined $p_{model}(x^{(i)}|\theta) \equiv p(x^{(i)})$. We can do it, as our model is actually not modeling probability of the sample $x^{(i)}$, so artificially defining $p_{model}(x^{(i)}|\theta) \equiv p(x^{(i)})$ does not have impact on the model, and is interpreted as *"we are modeling the probability of drawing $x^{(i)}$ as the true probability of this event (which is actually unknown, but we don't care)*". The last step is just a reformulation for those that would irritated by conditioning on $\theta$, and the resulting term is just simple cross-entropy minimization.

Comment: Thanks for putting this here. A clear description of this derivation is just what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

I was also wondering about the lack of information on rigorous derivation of the relationship between the conditional MLE (as this can be applied in supervised learning) and cross-entropy minimization on internet. My current explanation follows like this: 
$$\begin{eqnarray} 
\hat{\theta}_{ML} &=& \arg\max_{\theta} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^{N} \log p_{model}(y^{(i)}|x^{(i)};\theta) \nonumber \\
&=& \arg\min_{\theta} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^{N} - \log p_{model}(y^{(i)}|x^{(i)};\theta) \nonumber \\
 &\approx& \arg\min_{\theta} \left(\mathbb{E}_{p_{data}(x,y)}\left[ -\log p_{model}(y|x;\theta) \right] \right) \nonumber 
\end{eqnarray}$$
where $\mathbb{E}_{p_{data}(x,y)}$ is the expected value with respect to the distribution of the data $p_{data}(x,y)$ and the last line can be seen as  *conditional cross entropy*. Note that this term is really rarely used (I found only one paper using it, what wonders me) but this definition of conditional cross-entropy is consistent with the widely used definition of *conditional entropy*.

The main difference from your approach is, that the expected value is taken over the whole $X \times Y$ domain (taking the probability $p_{data}(x,y)$ instead of $p_{data}(y|x)$), therefore the conditional cross-entropy is not a random variable, but a number.

If you find in this approach any inaccuracies or a better explanation I'll be happy to read about it.

Comment: I also find this is not very well explained in most sources.  The cross entropy used as a loss function in DL seems to be implicitly defined like you define it, but I am struggling to find this made explicit in any reference text.  I would like to know if you do find a good reference...

Comment: @postylem , the only paper where I found conditional cross-entropy defined is this: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1809.00197.pdf . Conditional entropy which is similar is used more often and can be also found on wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_entropy . However, as you can see in my new answer below, I realized defining conditional cross-entropy is actually not even needed, and one can show the equivalence to standard cross entropy minimization directly.

Answer (score 0):

Your guess is correct.

Say the ground truth joint distribution of (data, label) is $p^*(x,y)$. This induces a ground truth distribution $p^*(y|x)$, which we try to model with $p_\theta(y|x)$.

Let's just suppose an infinite amount of samples are available, so all our Monte-Carlo approximations are exact. Then the conditional MLE objective is

$$
\mathbb{E}_{(x, y) \sim p^*(x,y)} [- \log p_\theta(y|x)].
$$

This is really just an integral w.r.t. the joint distribution, and by Fubini's theorem we can compute it by two nested integrals (where $x$ is held fixed in the inner one), resulting in the conditional cross-entropy,
$$
\mathbb{E}_{x \sim p^*(x)} [ \mathbb{E}_{y \sim p^*(y|x)} [- \log p_\theta(y|x)] ] = \mathbb{E}_{x \sim p^*(x)} [H[p^*(y|x),  p_\theta(y|x)] ].
$$

As @Igor remarked, this conditional cross-entropy takes a similar form as the conditional entropy.

Also see Appendix of B of [this note by Karl Stratos](https://karlstratos.com/notes/nce.pdf).